# Convert from decimal to any base number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, radix

This function takes in any base-10 integer and returns the string representation of that number in its specified base-32 form:

```
def encodeN(n,N,D="0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc"):
    return (encodeN(n//N,N)+D[n%N]).lstrip("0") if n>0 else "0"
```

Example:

```
print (encodeN(16002,32))
```

Output:

```
ya2
```

But I have a problem with writing a decoding function from base-32 back to base-10. How can I write it? Can I enter custom nonstandard characters to extend the base-n?

Comment: When you say "back to base-10", you're talking about converting from a base-32 string representation of an integer to a Python `int`, right? (Python `int`s aren't stored in base 10, so the "base-10" part is a bit misleading.)

Comment: yes, that's what I meant :)

Comment: Anything wrong with just using the built-in [`base64.b32encode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.b32encode) ?

Comment: @zwer: It doesn't use `"0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc"`, I guess.

Comment: @zwer everything works, but I wanted to write my coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could cheat:

```
tmap = str.maketrans('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv')
result = int(inputvalue.translate(tmap), 32)
```

Demo:

```
>>> tmap = str.maketrans('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv')
>>> inputvalue = 'ya2'
>>> int(inputvalue.translate(tmap), 32)
16002
```

`int()` is perfectly capable of translating arbitrary bases back to integer values; all you need to do is use the standard progression of letters. The `str.translate()` call above maps your custom progression to the standard.

Otherwise, take each character from your input string, starting at the left, map that to an integer from your character map, and multiply by the base N each time:

```
def decodeN(n, N, D={c: i for i, c in enumerate("0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc")}):
    result = 0
    for c in n:
        result = (result * N) + D[c]
    return result
```

This is the slower option; `str.translate()` and `int()` both use optimised C code to do their jobs, and will always be faster than a pure-python approach.

Translating that to a recursive version to match your `encodeN()` implementation:

```
def decodeN(n, N, D={c: i for i, c in enumerate("0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc")}):
    return decodeN(n[:-1], N) * N + D[n[-1]] if n else 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! the last answer is the best for me, because using the standard progression of letters would be a bit troublesome for me.

Answer (score 2):

With the same recursive structure, you could write:

```
def encodeN(n,N,D="0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc"):
    return (encodeN(n//N,N)+D[n%N]).lstrip("0") if n>0 else "0"

def decodeN(n,N,D="0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc"):
    return decodeN(n[:-1],N) * N + D.index(n[-1]) if n else 0
```

It seems to work fine:

```
print(encodeN(16002, 32))
# "ya2"
print(decodeN("ya2", 32))
# 16002
print(all(decodeN(encodeN(x, b), b) == x for b in range(2, 33) for x in range(10000)))
# True
print(all(encodeN(decodeN(str(x),32), 32) == str(x) for b in range(2, 33) for x in range(10000)))
# True
```

It's not very efficient though. Using a [dict like MartijnPieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47758504/6419007) would be a better idea than using `str.index`.

Comment: Go the whole hog and test all bases: `print(all(decodeN(encodeN(x, b), b) == x for b in range(2, 33) for x in range(10000)))`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I was just about to write those tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import string
>>> len(string.readable)
100
```

Judging by this you could have up to base 100 with no issues like duplicating characters or changing the encoding. But if we take out `\t\n\r\x0b\x0c` we get to 94.

Besides this you would have to result to some kind of custom rules, duplicating characters or prefixing them and such.