# Python base64.b32hexencode not creating expected result

Tags: python-3.x, base64, hex, base32

I expect the code to return `TPLIG0` as the base32 hex-extended value for 1 billion (1.000.000.000). Instead I get `7EDCK00=` .

Here is my code:

```
import base64
num = 1000000000
needed_bytes = num.to_bytes((num.bit_length() + 7) // 8, byteorder='big')
result = base64.b32hexencode(needed_bytes).decode('utf-8')
print(result)
```

I have tried with `b32hexencode`, `b32encode`, as well as `byteorder='little'` and `byteorder='big'`, but I cannot reproduce the expected result.

If I replace the division with the hardcoded number: `num.to_bytes(5, byteorder='big')` **I can get the approximate result:** `00TPLIG0` . But what is going on here??

I'm using `python 3.10.7`. on Windows and `3.11.0` on Ubuntu (both create same output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num.bit_length() + 7) // 8` is 4, not 5.  `b32hexencode` pads its result with `=` if not a multiple of 40 bits (5 bytes) and the bits are shifted.

```
>>> base64.b32hexencode (bytes([1,2,3,4]))
b'0410610='
>>> base64.b32hexencode (bytes([1,2,3,4,5]))
b'04106105'
```

Use `(num.bit_length() + 39) // 40 * 5` to calculate `needed_bytes` in multiples of 5 bytes, then strip leading zeroes to use `base64.b32hexencode()` correctly:

```
import base64
num = 1_000_000_000

def convert(n):
    if n == 0:  # b32hexencode() return '=====' for zero, so special handling
        return '0'
    num_bytes = (n.bit_length() + 39) // 40 * 5
    needed_bytes = n.to_bytes(num_bytes, byteorder='big')
    result = base64.b32hexencode(needed_bytes).lstrip(b'0')
    return result.decode() # bytes -> str

def display(n):
    result = convert(n)
    verify = int(result, 32)
    print(f'{result:>9} {verify:17,}')
    
display(num)
for i in range(9):
    n = 2**(i * 5)
    display(n - 1)
    display(n)
```

Output testing OP value and rolling over every 5-bit binary value:

```
   TPLIG0     1,000,000,000
        0                 0
        1                 1
        V                31
       10                32
       VV             1,023
      100             1,024
      VVV            32,767
     1000            32,768
     VVVV         1,048,575
    10000         1,048,576
    VVVVV        33,554,431
   100000        33,554,432
   VVVVVV     1,073,741,823
  1000000     1,073,741,824
  VVVVVVV    34,359,738,367
 10000000    34,359,738,368
 VVVVVVVV 1,099,511,627,775
100000000 1,099,511,627,776
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually trying to convert a decimal base number to base32. I don't think `base64` has been made for such use cases.

Converting from one base to another is already covered in other SO answers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758410/convert-from-decimal-to-any-base-number-in-python) for instance). In your case, you could implement the following function:

```
def base10to32(n,symbols="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV"):
    return (base10to32(n//32)+symbols[n%32]).lstrip("0") if n>0 else "0"

base10to32(1000000000)
```

Or if you prefer to use an existing module, `numpy` can handle this type of conversion:

```
import numpy as np
np.base_repr(1000000000, 32)
```

Output:

```
TPLIG0
```

Comment: Thanks for the great one-liner! I've marked @Mark 's answer as the solution as he solved the provided code. But your code is definitely the better way to go.